# How can I display all active sessions of logged in users using django-user-sessions?

Tags: python, django, session, usersession

Please I need someone to help me out on the django-user-sessions, I have tried the documentation but it is not showing me the full active sessions of the login user. Please I need help can someone show me the example views and template on how it should be. Thank you

I have tried the django-user-sessions documentation, I have installed django-user-sessions and put user-sessions in my installed apps.